# How to make request.GET appear in form field?

Tags: python, django

I am making a search refiner for my website, I am using a GET form which is passing the information to the URL. Currently when you click 'search' in the GET form and submit the data the form does not retain what you have selected. I am trying to achieve this by putting a 'value' field in the input which is equal to 'request.GET.xxxx'. I was able to get this to work for my keywords input when I wrote the input HTML myself and didnt load it via '{{ form.keywords}}' however I could not replicate this for my choice fields. Does anybody know how I could do this? Cheers!

HTML -

```
<div class="searchrefiner">
    <h2 class="searchrefiner-title">Job Finder</h2>
    <form class="qsm-form" action="{% url 'browse' %}" method="GET">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <p class="searchrefiner-field-title">Business Industry</p><br>
        {{ form.business_industry }}
        <p class="searchrefiner-field-title">Business Region</p><br>
        {{ form.business_address_region }}
        <p class="searchrefiner-field-title">Employment Type</p><br>
        {{ form.employment_type }}
        <p class="searchrefiner-field-title">Keywords</p><br>
        {{ form.keywords }}<br>
        <button type="submit" class="qsm-form-button">Search Jobs</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Form -

```
class JobSearchForm(forms.Form):
    employment_type = forms.ChoiceField(employment_type_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'qsm-form-input'}))
    business_address_region = forms.ChoiceField(region_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'qsm-form-input'}))
    business_industry = forms.ChoiceField(industry_choice, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'qsm-form-input', 'value': '{{ request.GET.business_industry }}'}))
    keywords = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'qsm-form-input', 'placeholder': 'Enter Keywords...', 'value': '{{ request.GET.keywords }}'}))
```

Comment: You should use ajax  to replace form.

Comment: You should look at edit View. The Form render the form but the view will handle your GET request and l return what needs to be display on the form.

Comment: Biobirdman, could you please elaborate a bit more? I dont quite understand what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do it this way at all. The form definition is for the *definition* of the fields, not their values; there's no access to the request data at that point, and you're just passing strings that look like template variable.s

This is a job for the view, and it's as simple as:

```
form = JobSearchForm(initial=request.GET)
```

Comment: This is such a simple way of doing this and is far superior to the JavaScript method I was just dabbling with. Works perfectly, really appreciate the help!